# Limit number of PHP requests per minute?

Tags: php, centos

I have a VB application that access a PHP file on my server, but sometimes it can glitch and make them access it multiple times within seconds and then it creates high load on the server.

Now so this doesn't happen, is there a way to limit 1 request per 30 seconds from every unique person requesting the PHP file? I don't want it to limit the whole server to 1 request per 30 seconds, I want it to be a 1 request per 30 seconds for every user individually.

I have no idea how I can do this, can anyone help?

EDIT:
Picture of what it looks like: [image]

Comment: are you using curl or ajax for hitting the php script?

Comment: if you are using ajax you can use settimeout function

Comment: @VikasUmrao Neither, I am using HTTP requests from VB.NET to the PHP file on the site.

Comment: @VikasUmrao I do have a timeout function for 10 seconds, but the thing is, it requests the same file by the same user many times at the same time. Look at the post for a picture ^

Comment: is it auto or user hitting the submit button

Comment: how it settimeout going to help here? He only wants a unique person to be restricted for a limited amount of time.

Comment: @VikasUmrao It is automatic, user does not intentionally hit the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a condition based on a non defined user entity or a fixed maximum frequency or delay  is not a good approach here because you will end up falsely stating that a user is defined by an IP

If your problem is a CPU load than you can use the code below on the beginning of your php file :

```
$cpu_load_max = 1; 
$cpu_load_current = sys_getloadavg();
if ($cpu_load_current[0] > $cpu_load_max) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Too busy, try again later');
    die('Server too busy. Please try again later.');
    // Or whatever you want
}
```